How to Automatically Track and Alert on Logs in OpenShift with Zabbix?
I have a project deployed on OpenShift namespace "alianz" with two deployments (front-end and back-end) each with 2 replicas. I need to automatically track logs and trigger alerts if certain keywords like "exception" or "error" are detected.
We also use Zabbix for server monitoring. What’s the best way to capture and analyze these logs in OpenShift, and how can I configure Zabbix to monitor these logs and send alerts based on specific keywords?
Any recommendations or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
I try to use prometheus but i think it provide just numeric data and not logs
